# How to download file from server and save it with dialog

Tags: javascript, download, dialog

I am trying to download a file from a target `server` and upon receiving the file i'd like to get a dialog opened and let me choose where to save it.

So far i just used for simple download:

```
<a class="button" type="application/octet-stream"  href="http://localhost:5300/get" download>Click here for dld</a>
```

I have read that i need to use the `FileApi` in order to achieve this but still it is not usable for all browsers.

How can i manage to get the dialog opened ?

Comment: JavaScript can't control the file dialog, it depends on the user's preferences. It will either save to their default download location or pop up a dialog based on browser settings.

Comment: So i can't force a popup dialog ?

Comment: No, you can't. It's the user's choice.

Comment: There are many security restrictions upon interacting of a website with a local OS. Especially messing with the file system is strictly regulated. You can only have minimal, but indirect access to the file system via cookies or localStorage/sessionStorage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `jquery.fileDownload.js` which help to handle download operation

> http://jqueryfiledownload.apphb.com/

Answer (score 1):

Just use that

`<a href="data:application/octet-stream;charset=utf-8,your code here" download="filename.extension">Save as</a>`